# Chat bot differentiating "Know" and "No" in Java

Tags: java, chatbot, indexof

I am making a simple chat bot in Java for my AP Java class in high school. My bot needs to print out "Why so negative" when imputed a sentence with "no" in it and also needs to print out "I didn't know that" when imputed a sentence with "know" in it. My bot consistently prints out "Why so negative" when "know" is imputed due to the no in know. Can anyone help recommend a solution for me?

I have tried everything thing I have learned in Java so far and cant find a solution

```
if (statement.indexOf("No") >= 0)
{                   
response = "Why so negative?";
}
else if (statement.indexOf("Know") >= 0)
{
response = "I didn't know that!";
}
```

Comment: `if (statement.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) { ... }` else etc...

Comment: Have you tried switching the order you test these things?

Answer (score 0):

```
statement.equalsIgnoreCase("No")){
response = "Why so negative?";
}
```

.equalsIgnoreCase can be used to compare a string (your statement) with another string ("No", "know"...) while ignoring case. If you need to be case sensitive, use .equals("...")

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work if you switch your `if` statements

```
if (statement.indexOf("Know") >= 0) {
    response = "Why so negative?";
} else if (statement.indexOf("No") >= 0) {
    response = "I didn't know that!";
}
```

Note that `indexOf` is case-sensitive, so if you want your bot to handle this cases, you should first convert your input to lower case like this:

```
String lower = statement.toLowerCase();
if (lower.indexOf("know") >= 0) {                   
    response = "Why so negative?";
} else if (lower.indexOf("no") >= 0) {
    response = "I didn't know that!";
}
```

**Edit** Using regular expresions would be safer for cases when your input contains words other than "know" with "no" in them

This is an example:

```
String lower = statement.toLowerCase();
if (lower.matches(".*(^| )no( |$).*")) {
    response = "Why so negative?";
} else if (lower.matches(".*(^| )know( |$).*") {
    response = "I didn't know that!";
}
```